# How do I find Byte patterns in a byte array,reprsent it if its available in checkedlistbox in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make software to search for byte patterns, I have many bin files and many patterns to search. If the pattern exists on the file. it will represent it on CheckedListBox with a specific name . and if the checked box is checked for a particular one , it will replace the pattern with 0000000000 on the saved file.
For example, I have this pattern to search (note that I have more than 100 patterns to search):
`{"2004940101000078", "3004940101000078", "3E04940101000028", .... ,.... }`

- Open the bin file by OpenFileDialog
- Covert the file to byteArray
- Search for the patterns
- put the result on checkedlist Box
  (2004940101000078 = P0420) (3004940101000078 = P0430) (3E04940101000028 =P043E),note P0420 is the    name that i want to put on the checkedbox:

| DTC | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Checkedbox P0420 | Catalyst System Efficiency Below Threshold Bank1 |
| Checkedbox P0430 | Catalyst System Efficiency Below Threshold Bank2 |
| Checkedbox P043E | EvaporativeEmissionSystemLeakDetectionReferenceOrificeLowFlow |

- If I want to delete the code P0420 , checkbox P0420 `replace 2004940101000078 with 0000000000000000` and save it to a new bin file

I tried with this code to search for the patterns, but its give the offset position of the pattern only. please this code-only example and part of my codes.if you have a solution or other code or way. please help, I am new in C#

```cs
string hex2 = BitConverter.ToString(byteArray).Replace("-", string.Empty);
string[] patterns = {"2004940101000078", "3004940101000078", "3E04940101000028" };

foreach (string p in patterns)
{
    int i = 0;
    int indice = 0;

    // teminate loop when no more occurrence is found;
    
    while (indice != -1)
    {
        // index if the pattern is found AFTER i position, -1 if not
        indice = hex2.IndexOf(p, i);

        
        i = indice + 0; // skip the pattern occurrence itself
        int indexxx = (i / 2);
        
        //Transform the index into hexadecimal
        string outputHex = int.Parse(indexxx.ToString()).ToString("X");

        //Output the index as an hexadecimal offset address
        MessageBox.Show("0x" + outputHex);

        break;
    }
}
```

thank you

Comment: 1) directly after that IndexOf, you should test the value of 'indice' to quit the loop when it is -1 (the `while` doesn't exit immediately when that condition is true). 2) You do not want a `break` at the end of the loop: this always exits the loop after the first iteration. 3) MessageBox.Show is fine for debugging, but you want to return the positions per pattern, so you will need to remember them

Answer (score 2):

You are checking the hex string versions of the byte arrays. This means

- You can easily use IndexOf to find a match - great
- You will use 4 times as much memory (one `byte` = two 16-bit `char`s)
- You can have "false positives": searching for "1234" will find it in "512346" - you will have to check whether that can be a problem, or better, just guard against it (keep searching if you find an odd index)

If you want to remember where the match was and link it to certain buttons, don't use a `List<string>` but a `List<PatternMatch>` where PatternMatch is:

```
public class PatternMatch
{
   public string HexPattern {get;set;} // the pattern to search for
   public int HexIndex {get;set;} = -2; // the index where it was found, -1=not found, -2=not searched yet
   public string Name {get;set;} // the button name, like P0420, P0430
   public bool ToErase {get;set;} // whether to erase the matched pattern from the input
}
```

and then something like:

```
 // the source to search in
string hex2 = BitConverter.ToString(byteArray).Replace("-", string.Empty);

// your patterns and button names
List<PatternMatch> patterns = new List<PatternMatch>(); 
patterns.Add(new PatternMatch { HexPattern = "2004940101000078", Name = "P0420" });
patterns.Add(new PatternMatch { HexPattern = "3004940101000078", Name = "P0430" });
patterns.Add(new PatternMatch { HexPattern = "3E04940101000028", Name = "P043E" });
// etc

foreach(var pattern in patterns)
{
   // initialise search position
   pattern.HexIndex = -1;
   do
   {
      // try and find next match
      pattern.HexIndex = hex2.IndexOf(pattern.HexPattern, pattern.HexIndex+1);

     // repeat while there was something found, but at an odd index (false positive)
   } while (pattern.HexIndex != -1 && index % 2 == 1);
   // NB: in the original byte[] use half of pattern.HexIndex

   if (pattern.HexIndex == -1)
      Debug.WriteLine($"pattern {pattern.HexPattern} not found");
   else
      Debug.WriteLine($"pattern {pattern.HexPattern} found at byte index {pattern.HexIndex/2}");
}
```

---

Then you can use that "patterns" list to match/fill your checkboxes, using `pattern.Name` to find the corresponding checkbox.
When the checkbox is checked, set the corresponding `pattern.ToErase` to `true`.

You can do it by handling the "checked changed" event.

Assuming winforms with [CheckBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox). you can set the [Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag) property to the name (like "P0420"). Then you can find out what pattern this checkbox belongs to, independent of what you display.

Then you will need to handle the [Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click) event for all checkboxes using one method:

```
private void PatternCheckbox_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   var cb = (CheckBox)sender;
   var name = (string)cb.Tag; // The type of Tag is 'object', so you need a cast

   var pattern = patterns.Single(p => p.Name == name); // find the corresponding one
   pattern.ToErase = cd.Checked; // set 'ToErase to match the checkbox state
}
```

Or when you use a [CheckedListBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox) then, in your **Save method**, use its [CheckedItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditemcollection) to get the checked items so you can set the corresponding ToErase flag:

```
// TODO fix some names to match your code
foreach(object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
   // TODO cast 'itemChecked' to the correct type
   var myitem = (MyItem)itemChecked;

   // TODO get its name ("P0420" etc)
   string name = myitem.Name;

   var pattern = patterns.Single(p => p.Name == name); // find the corresponding pattern
   pattern.ToErase = true; // the CheckedItems only returns checked items (and indeterminate)

}
```

Then you can start to perform the erasures.

---

When the user clicks "Save", you can loop through the patterns and see which have set ToErase to `true`. Then you can replace the corresponding HexPattern at the HexIndex that was found with zeroes.

Tip: `new string('0', HexPattern.Length)` has exactly enough 0's to cover that pattern.

This should do the erasures:

```
// process the marked patterns that correspond to a real match
foreach (var toErase in patterns.Where(p => p.ToErase && p.HexIndex >= 0))
{
   // first remove the old pattern, then insert 0's 
   // (Replace would replace all occurrences, not just the one at the index you found)
   hex2 = hex2.Remove(toErase.HexIndex, toErase.HexPattern.Length)
              .Insert(toErase.HexIndex, new string('0', toErase.HexPattern.Length));
}
```

Comment: I extended the code a bit. I don't know how your checkboxes are defined: you will need to select a checkbox that belongs to name "P0430", can you?

Comment: Thanks again for your time, actually I have two buttons, one for reading the file via ofd and one to save to new file,and I have checkedListBox1 when the file is loaded it will show available dtcs code such P0420 and so on,, when user click unchecked on P0420 and then press the save button, its should replace the pattern of p0420 which is 2004940101000078  with 0000000000000000..

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are describing. You may need to post a new question, with more details about this part of your problem. You can link to this question.

Comment: sorry my native language is not English, thanks, now it's working to load the correct dtcs on the checkedListBox1,, now when the user is unchecked for example P0420, how it can be done. unchecked the P0420 then click the save button. what should I do in checkedlistBox1

Comment: That last part? Yes, it should run *after* the user is done selecting patterns to erase. Don't forget to convert that hex-string back to bytes

Comment: appreciated your help again in the code to erase the patterns. where should I put this code, Save Button?I try it but doesn't work , did I miss something to add before your code

Comment: Did you set that ToErase property to true for checked checkboxes? And yes, the handler for the click event of that Save button is a fine place for that last fragment

Comment: Can you please help on this issue , I can't figure out how I can solve it. really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: I added code for checkbox handling, assuming you are using winforms

Comment: Thank you again, but I can't make it work. Yes its winforms ,as you know I have two buttons, one to load the file and one to save the file and I have checkedListbox1 which is load successfully the dtcs  (P0420,P0430, and so on, from corresponding patterns).in your code to for checkbox handling. Do you want me to add a new button for deleting the checked dtc? and var cb = (CheckBox)sender; ,,,,Checkbox : do you mean check checkedListBox1?

Comment: You may need to use [CheckedItemCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditemcollection), in your save-button handler instead of the solution for individual checkboxes I posted. See also the example there

Comment: I added some more code, but you will need to adjust it to your situation (I don't know what variables and types you use)

Comment: That "MyItem" is the class you use to feed the checkbox list. You will need to adjust that to what you use - as I don't know those details about *your* code. Try and understand the code samples I provided and adjust them to your needs

Comment: You will need "some way" (that *you* will have to define, based on *your* code) to get from the checked items in that checkedlistbox1 to the correct pattern in the "patterns" list, so you can set its "ToErase" property to true. I cannot help you there

Comment: thank you, but now I have an error: StartIndex cannot be less than zero. (Parameter 'startIndex')

Comment: I guess it's time to learn [debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), so you can see what values you have and *why*